# get rid of the top and bottom bars on samsung galaxy s3 camera

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile

I'm launching the camera app from my app. Can I get rid of those bars at the top and bottom?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: go to Settings -> Photo size and pick resolution with aspect ratio 16:9 instead of 4:3.

Hope it'll help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.
If you want a custom UX for taking picture implements your own camera.

You can read on [android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) or other [site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html).